# Selenium chromedriver is not working, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

When I run this code it works perfectly fine, the chrome pop up but after few seconds chrome browser just close itself. Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: Is there some log? what is your Chrome version and Chromedriver version?

Comment: Version 96.0.4664.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: chromedriver is win32

Comment: Does the chrome driver version match your current version of chrome?

Comment: Have you downloaded the chromedriver for this page: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/ ? If not so, do this, add chromedriver to your path and try again.

Comment: @JailtonSilva wouldn't this page: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads also be an expectable download location?

Comment: there is no code after `driver.get("https://www.google.com")` so it is expected that it will get closed. was google.com launched ?

Comment: Try adding the following lines to see if the browser remains open. `import time` and `time.sleep(120)`. If so that would mean your browser just closed because your code was successfully run.